# Html Three elements on the same line

Tags: html, css

I am trying to put three h4 elements on the same line, I tried using display:inline-block; on all of them, but that only put two of the elements on the same line, the third one is under them.

Here is my HTML

```
            <h4 id="vbottomcreator"><a style="color:orange;">></a> Created by <a style="color:orange;"><</a></h4>
            <h4 id="vbottomdates" align="center"><a style="color:orange;">></a> tasdf <a style="color:orange;"><</a></h4>
            <h4 id="vbottomdevelopment"><a style="color:orange;">></a> Website still in Development <a style="color:orange;"><</a></h4>
```

The third element is under the rest

CSS

```
    #vbottomdates
    {
        color:black;
        display:inline-block;
        margin-left:362px;
    }
    #vbottomcreator
    {
        color:black;
        margin-left:30px;
        display:inline-block;
    }
    #vbottomdevelopment
    {
        color:black;
        margin-left:1100px;
        display:inline-block;
        clear:none;
    }
```

QUESTION SOLVED

Comment: margin value is more for the last id.. Try to reduce the value.. you can get it in same line..

Comment: why not to put them in one H4?
you are not gaining anything having 3 different tags

Comment: I need to have one h4 on the left, one in the middle, and one on the right. I don't think I can reduce the value with having it the way I want it.

Comment: "QUESTION SOLVED"? None of the answers are marked as accepted. Did one of them work for you? If so, you should mark it as accepted. If you came up with your own solution add it as an answer and mark it as accepted. I believe there is a delay before you can accept your own answer but adding it and marking it as the accepted answer will help anyone who might be having a similar problem and comes across this in the future.

Comment: -1 should have accepted an answer. In case none of the given answers were any good, you could have answered your own question with the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Try like this: **[Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qs1jgn9x/3/)**

**HTML:**

```
<div class="center">
    <h4>...</h4>
     <h4>...</h4>
    <h4>...</h4>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#vbottomdates {
    color:black;
    display:block;
    float:left;
}
#vbottomcreator {
    color:black;
    display:inline-block;
}
#vbottomdevelopment {
    color:black;
    display:block;
    float:right;
    display:inline-block;
}
.center {
    width:100%;
    margin:0 auto;
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Margin value is more for the last id.. Try to reduce the value like this.. all the 3 elements were placed properly

Comment: I said this in a previous comment above, I need to have each one of the h4 elements in a different position, right, middle, and left. I can't exactly reduce the value with me wanting to do this.

Comment: Try to mention clearly in your question at first.. So you can get appropriate answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Reduce the margin left value:

```
#vbottomdevelopment
{
    color:black;
    margin-left:500px;
    display:inline-block;
    clear:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am wondering why are you using margin-left to place all elements horizontally. You will seriously have to change it in future, as it will enable horizontal scroll if window size is reduced. In other words, your page will never be responsive.

remove all margin-left property and give some width in percentage such that total width of all blocks remains less than 100% width of window.
This will ensure that even if user reduces window size, your elements will be in correct position.

[Check DEMO here](http://jsbin.com/datumububo/1/edit?html,css,output)

HTML

```
  <h4 id="vbottomcreator" class="vbottom"><a style="color:orange;">></a> Created by <a style="color:orange;"><</a></h4>

  <h4 id="vbottomdates" align="center" class="vbottom"><a style="color:orange;">></a> tasdf <a style="color:orange;"><</a></h4>

  <h4 id="vbottomdevelopment" class="vbottom"><a style="color:orange;">></a> Website still in Development <a style="color:orange;"><</a></h4>
```

CSS

```
#vbottomdates
{
    color:black;
    display:inline-block;

}
#vbottomcreator
{
    color:black;
    display:inline-block;
}
#vbottomdevelopment
{
    color:black;
    display:inline-block;
    clear:none;
}

.vbottom {
    width : 30%;
}
```